# Fast outer tensor product in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have two numpy arrays:

```
x of shape ((d1,...,d_m)) 
y of shape ((e_1,...e_n))
```

I would like to form the outer tensor product, that is the numpy array

```
z of shape ((d1,...,d_m,e_1,...,e_n))
```

such that

```
z[i_1,...,i_n,i_{n+1}...,i_{m+n}] == x[i_1,...i_m]*y[i_{m+1},...,i_{m+n}]
```

I have to perform the above outer multiplication several times so I would like to speed this up as much as possible.

Comment: insert dummy data with your expected result to understand better what do you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `outer` is to explicitly expand the dimensions.  For 1d arrays this would be

```
x[:,None]*y   # y[None,:] is automatic.
```

For 10x10 arrays, and generalizing the dimension expansion, I get the same times

```
In [74]: timeit x[[slice(None)]*x.ndim + [None]*y.ndim] * y
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.6 µs per loop

In [75]: timeit np.multiply.outer(x,y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.6 µs per loop
```

So `outer` does save some coding, but the basic broadcasted multiplication  is the same.

Answer (score 6):

You want [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
z = np.multiply.outer(x, y)
```

Comment: That's it! Am I right to assume that since ufunc is part of numpy, it calls C code and there won't be a significantly faster way to do this?