# numpy multiplication table ouptut

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

Im a newbie to numpy and trying to find a efficient way to write mult table using numpy.

```
def mult_table():
    result = []
    for i in a:
        for j in a:
            result.append(i*j)
    return result
```

In numpy I see a dot matrix and a matmul but not sure how to replicate the above logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464737/fast-outer-tensor-product-in-numpy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast outer tensor product in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464737/fast-outer-tensor-product-in-numpy)

Answer (score 11):

One way is to use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). You can easily wrap this in a function.

```
import numpy as np

def mult_table(n):
    rng = np.arange(1, n+1)
    return rng * rng[:, None]

print(mult_table(5))

# [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 2  4  6  8 10]
#  [ 3  6  9 12 15]
#  [ 4  8 12 16 20]
#  [ 5 10 15 20 25]]
```